# I need to make the bricks randomly red or blue

Tags: javascript

Here's all the code (The variables are named properly so you should understand it)

The problem is that it resets **all** the bricks' colors randomly to red or blue but I want it to give a random color to **each** brick instead (70% of the time blue and 30% of the time red ).

```js
var canvas, canvasContext;

var ballX = 75,
  ballY = 75;
var ballSpeedX = 3,
  ballSpeedY = 3;
var ballR = 7;

const brickW = 80;
const brickH = 20;
const brickCols = Math.floor(800 / brickW);
const brickRows = Math.floor(600 / (brickH * 3));
const brickGap = 1;
var brickGrid = new Array(brickCols * brickRows);
var bricksLeft = 0;

const paddleW = 100,
  paddleH = 10;
var paddleX = 400,
  paddleY = 600;
const distanceBP = 60;

var mouseX, mouseY;

function updateMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // this is for adjustments only (getting the mouse coordinates even if the page is scrollable)
  var root = document.documentElement;

  mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft; // clientX is the X of mouse 
  mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;

  paddleX = mouseX - paddleW / 2;
  //cheat
  //ballX = mouseX;
  //ballY = mouseY;
}

function brickReset() {
  bricksLeft = 0;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3 * brickCols; i++) {
    brickGrid[i] = false;
  }
  for (; i < brickCols * brickRows; i++) {
    brickGrid[i] = true;
    bricksLeft++;
    randBrickColor();
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var fps = 60;
  setInterval(updateAll, 1000 / fps);

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePos); // everytime the mouse moves we call the function updateMousePos()
  brickReset();
  ballReset();
}

function updateAll() {
  drawAll();
  moveAll();
  console.log(brickColor);
}

function ballReset() {
  ballX = canvas.width / 2;
  ballY = canvas.height / 2;
}

function ballMove() {
  ballX += ballSpeedX;
  ballY += ballSpeedY;
  //COLLISION

  //left
  if (ballX - ballR < 0 && ballSpeedX < 0.0) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  }
  //right
  if (ballX + ballR > canvas.width && ballSpeedX > 0.0) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  }
  //top
  if (ballY - ballR < 0 && ballSpeedY < 0.0) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }

  //bottom
  if (ballY > canvas.height) {
    ballReset();
    brickReset();
  }
}

function isBrickAtColRow(col, row) {
  if (col >= 0 && col < brickCols &&
    row >= 0 && row < brickRows) {
    var brickIndexUnderCoord = rowColToArrayIndex(col, row);
    return brickGrid[brickIndexUnderCoord];

  } else {
    return false;
  }

}

function ballBrickHandling() {
  var ballBrickCol = Math.floor(ballX / brickW);
  var ballBrickRow = Math.floor(ballY / brickH);
  var brickIndexUnderBall = rowColToArrayIndex(ballBrickCol, ballBrickRow);

  if (brickIndexUnderBall >= 0 &&
    brickIndexUnderBall < brickCols * brickRows) {

    if (isBrickAtColRow(ballBrickCol, ballBrickRow)) {
      brickGrid[brickIndexUnderBall] = false;
      bricksLeft--;
      //console.log( bricksLeft)

      var prevBallX = ballX - ballSpeedX;
      var prevBallY = ballY - ballSpeedY;
      var prevBrickCol = Math.floor(prevBallX / brickW);
      var prevBrickRow = Math.floor(prevBallY / brickH);

      var bothTestsFailed = true;

      if (prevBrickCol != ballBrickCol) {

        if (isBrickAtColRow(prevBrickCol, ballBrickRow) == false) {
          ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
          bothTestsFailed = false;
        }
      }
      if (prevBrickRow != ballBrickRow) {

        if (isBrickAtColRow(ballBrickCol, prevBrickRow) == false) {
          ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
          bothTestsFailed = false;
        }
      }

      if (bothTestsFailed) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
      }
    }
  }
}

function ballPaddleHandling() {
  var paddleTopEdgeY = canvas.height - distanceBP;
  var paddleBottomEdgeY = paddleTopEdgeY + paddleH;
  var paddleLeftEdgeX = paddleX;
  var paddleRightEdgeX = paddleLeftEdgeX + paddleW;
  if (ballY + ballR > paddleTopEdgeY &&
    ballY - ballR < paddleBottomEdgeY &&
    ballX + ballR > paddleLeftEdgeX &&
    ballX - ballR < paddleRightEdgeX) {

    ballSpeedY *= -1;

    var centerOfPaddleX = paddleX + paddleW / 2;
    var ballDistFromPadlleCenterX = ballX - centerOfPaddleX;
    ballSpeedX = ballDistFromPadlleCenterX * 0.2;

    if (bricksLeft == 0) {
      brickReset();
    }
  }

}

function moveAll() {
  //console.log("X: "+ballSpeedX,"Y: "+ballSpeedY);

  ballMove();

  ballBrickHandling();

  ballPaddleHandling();

}

function rowColToArrayIndex(col, row) {
  return col + brickCols * row;
}

// Random COLOR
var brickColor = "blue";

function randBrickColor() {

  if (Math.random() > 0.7) {
    brickColor = "red";
  } else brickColor = "blue";

  return brickColor;
}
//end of Random COLOR

function drawBricks() {
  for (var eachRow = 0; eachRow < brickRows; eachRow++) {
    for (var eachCol = 0; eachCol < brickCols; eachCol++) {

      var arrayIndex = brickCols * eachRow + eachCol;

      if (brickGrid[arrayIndex]) {
        colorRect(brickW * eachCol, brickH * eachRow, brickW - brickGap, brickH - brickGap, brickColor);
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawAll() {
  // Black Screen
  colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");
  // Ball
  colorCircle(ballX, ballY, ballR, "white");
  // Paddle
  colorRect(paddleX, paddleY - distanceBP, paddleW, paddleH, "white");
  // Bricks
  drawBricks();

  colorText(mouseX + "," + mouseY, mouseX, mouseY, "yellow");
}

function colorRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
}

function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}

function colorText(showWords, textX, textY, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.fillText(showWords, textX, textY);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Provide more details, what are these bricks? Where do you want them to be shown?

Comment: you'll have to loop through each brick

Comment: Without seeing more code, it's hard to say, but what are you doing with the brickColor that you return? It looks like you're setting the global color when you call randBrickColor, but you're not actually using it in your loop.

Comment: Show the use of brickColor.
Also, I think you'd want to put the brickColor inside the randBrickColor.

Comment: You have **one** variable for the brick color and you use it to paint them all. Hardly you can have different colors if you don't keep track of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the color once per brick but you overwrite the global variable before you do any drawing. So when it gets to `drawBricks` the loop that sets the brick colors has already finished and the variable stays the same throughout the drawing.

Since you repaint the bricks continuously (I'm not sure if it is necessary) I suggest you save a bidimensional array of randomized colors in you `randBrickColor` function instead of just a variable.

A summary of the changes:

- Put the `randBrickColor();` call outside the loop in `brickReset()`.
- Initialize a variable `brickColors` (instead of `brickColor`) as an array. Ex: `var brickColors = [];`
- Change the function `randBrickColor` so it loops through `brickRows`and `brickCols` and stores the randomized color under `brickColors[eachRow][eachCol]`.
- Use `brickColors[eachRow][eachCol]` in your `drawBricks` function to pick the color of each brick.

See the snippet below.

```js
var canvas, canvasContext;

var ballX = 75,
  ballY = 75;
var ballSpeedX = 3,
  ballSpeedY = 3;
var ballR = 7;

const brickW = 80;
const brickH = 20;
const brickCols = Math.floor(800 / brickW);
const brickRows = Math.floor(600 / (brickH * 3));
const brickGap = 1;
var brickGrid = new Array(brickCols * brickRows);
var bricksLeft = 0;

const paddleW = 100,
  paddleH = 10;
var paddleX = 400,
  paddleY = 600;
const distanceBP = 60;

var mouseX, mouseY;

function updateMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // this is for adjustments only (getting the mouse coordinates even if the page is scrollable)
  var root = document.documentElement;

  mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft; // clientX is the X of mouse 
  mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;

  paddleX = mouseX - paddleW / 2;
  //cheat
  //ballX = mouseX;
  //ballY = mouseY;
}

function brickReset() {
  bricksLeft = 0;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3 * brickCols; i++) {
    brickGrid[i] = false;
  }
  for (; i < brickCols * brickRows; i++) {
    brickGrid[i] = true;
    bricksLeft++;
  }
  randBrickColor();
}

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var fps = 60;
  setInterval(updateAll, 1000 / fps);

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePos); // everytime the mouse moves we call the function updateMousePos()
  brickReset();
  ballReset();
}

function updateAll() {
  drawAll();
  moveAll();
}

function ballReset() {
  ballX = canvas.width / 2;
  ballY = canvas.height / 2;
}

function ballMove() {
  ballX += ballSpeedX;
  ballY += ballSpeedY;
  //COLLISION

  //left
  if (ballX - ballR < 0 && ballSpeedX < 0.0) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  }
  //right
  if (ballX + ballR > canvas.width && ballSpeedX > 0.0) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  }
  //top
  if (ballY - ballR < 0 && ballSpeedY < 0.0) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
  }

  //bottom
  if (ballY > canvas.height) {
    ballReset();
    brickReset();
  }
}

function isBrickAtColRow(col, row) {
  if (col >= 0 && col < brickCols &&
    row >= 0 && row < brickRows) {
    var brickIndexUnderCoord = rowColToArrayIndex(col, row);
    return brickGrid[brickIndexUnderCoord];

  } else {
    return false;
  }

}

function ballBrickHandling() {
  var ballBrickCol = Math.floor(ballX / brickW);
  var ballBrickRow = Math.floor(ballY / brickH);
  var brickIndexUnderBall = rowColToArrayIndex(ballBrickCol, ballBrickRow);

  if (brickIndexUnderBall >= 0 &&
    brickIndexUnderBall < brickCols * brickRows) {

    if (isBrickAtColRow(ballBrickCol, ballBrickRow)) {
      brickGrid[brickIndexUnderBall] = false;
      bricksLeft--;
      //console.log( bricksLeft)

      var prevBallX = ballX - ballSpeedX;
      var prevBallY = ballY - ballSpeedY;
      var prevBrickCol = Math.floor(prevBallX / brickW);
      var prevBrickRow = Math.floor(prevBallY / brickH);

      var bothTestsFailed = true;

      if (prevBrickCol != ballBrickCol) {

        if (isBrickAtColRow(prevBrickCol, ballBrickRow) == false) {
          ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
          bothTestsFailed = false;
        }
      }
      if (prevBrickRow != ballBrickRow) {

        if (isBrickAtColRow(ballBrickCol, prevBrickRow) == false) {
          ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
          bothTestsFailed = false;
        }
      }

      if (bothTestsFailed) {
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
      }
    }
  }
}

function ballPaddleHandling() {
  var paddleTopEdgeY = canvas.height - distanceBP;
  var paddleBottomEdgeY = paddleTopEdgeY + paddleH;
  var paddleLeftEdgeX = paddleX;
  var paddleRightEdgeX = paddleLeftEdgeX + paddleW;
  if (ballY + ballR > paddleTopEdgeY &&
    ballY - ballR < paddleBottomEdgeY &&
    ballX + ballR > paddleLeftEdgeX &&
    ballX - ballR < paddleRightEdgeX) {

    ballSpeedY *= -1;

    var centerOfPaddleX = paddleX + paddleW / 2;
    var ballDistFromPadlleCenterX = ballX - centerOfPaddleX;
    ballSpeedX = ballDistFromPadlleCenterX * 0.2;

    if (bricksLeft == 0) {
      brickReset();
    }
  }

}

function moveAll() {
  //console.log("X: "+ballSpeedX,"Y: "+ballSpeedY);

  ballMove();

  ballBrickHandling();

  ballPaddleHandling();

}

function rowColToArrayIndex(col, row) {
  return col + brickCols * row;
}

// Random COLOR
var brickColors = [];

function randBrickColor() {
  for (var eachRow = 0; eachRow < brickRows; eachRow++) {
    brickColors[eachRow] = [];
    for (var eachCol = 0; eachCol < brickCols; eachCol++) {
      if (Math.random() > 0.7) {
        brickColors[eachRow][eachCol] = "red";
      } else brickColors[eachRow][eachCol] = "blue";
    }
  }
}
//end of Random COLOR

function drawBricks() {
  for (var eachRow = 0; eachRow < brickRows; eachRow++) {
    for (var eachCol = 0; eachCol < brickCols; eachCol++) {

      var arrayIndex = brickCols * eachRow + eachCol;

      if (brickGrid[arrayIndex]) {
        colorRect(brickW * eachCol, brickH * eachRow, brickW - brickGap, brickH - brickGap, brickColors[eachRow][eachCol]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function drawAll() {
  // Black Screen
  colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");
  // Ball
  colorCircle(ballX, ballY, ballR, "white");
  // Paddle
  colorRect(paddleX, paddleY - distanceBP, paddleW, paddleH, "white");
  // Bricks
  drawBricks();

  colorText(mouseX + "," + mouseY, mouseX, mouseY, "yellow");
}

function colorRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
}

function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}

function colorText(showWords, textX, textY, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.fillText(showWords, textX, textY);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```